# Quebrar um numero em partes iguais

Tags: php

Tenho a variável `$peso` que oscila entre 1000 até 50000 (gramas)

Existe uma tabela de fretes que tenho como

```
1000a2000 => 10,00  
2000a3000 => 20,00
```

...

```
9000a10000 => 100,00  
kg_adicional => 2,25
```

Tenho *ifs* até 10000(gramas), acima disso eu deveria calcular o valor adicional, por exemplo

```
$peso = 18000
```

Tenho que pegar o valor de 9000a10000(R$ 100,00) e adicionar mais 8 KG, porém não sei como fazer para quebrar essa variável e fazer a validação.

Comment: Como é sua tabela ? Como você puxa esses dados ? Array ?

Comment: (KG - VALOR MAXIMO) * 2,25.

Comment: O que você quer dizer com `quebrar`?

Comment: Você fala em quebrar "9000a10000" (por exemplo), em duas variavel ou um array com tamanho 2?

Comment: if ($peso>10000) { $total = 100+ ($peso-10000)*2.25}. Sua dúvida é na fórmula??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se as quantidades são proporcionais, não é nem necessário usar *ifs*:

```
1000a2000 => 10,00  
2000a3000 => 20,00  
3000a4000 => 30,00  
4000a5000 => 40,00  
5000a6000 => 50,00  
6000a7000 => 60,00  
7000a8000 => 70,00  
8000a9000 => 80,00  
9000a10000 => 90,00 (aqui é 90 ou 100?)
```

Em tese, a seguinte fórmula já resolve.

```
$peso_excedente = $peso - 10000;
$peso_nominal = $peso - $peso_excedente;
$total = (floor($peso_nominal / 1000) * 10) + (floor($peso_excedente / 1000) * 2.25);
```